# Storing the result of a mongodb find() in a connect-mongo session store

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I currently have a mongodb session store setup in my Express web app. I know how to set individual fields like this:

`request.session.loggedIn = true;`

I'd like to simply store all of the fields in the result object instead of specifying them one-by-one, kind of like this:

```
targetcol.find({username: uname, password: pw}).toArray(function(err, results) {
    if( err || !results)
        console.error(err);
    else {
        console.log("login success");
        request.session = results[0];
    }
}
```

With the `request.session = results[0];` being the part that assigns the entire JSON object to the session store. Is this possible or do I have to do it individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to include [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com), the [extend()](http://lodash.com/docs#assign) function can be used to copy all properties of `results[0]` to `session` by

`request.session = _.extend(request.session, results[0]);`

But beware of any property in `session` will be overwritten by property of the same name in `results[0]`.